# Entity Framework creates 2 databases for the same schema and uses the wrong one

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.2.0 with Code First approach.

When I try to update the database by adding a new migration it creates a database with the updated changes. However, If I try to use a context instance in code it creates another database without the changes.

I couldn't find anyone else having this problem. Maybe I am doing something wrong
Here are the steps I use to update the database.

**Let's say I want to create an initial migration.**

I start with writing `Add-Migration Initial` and `Update-Database` to the `NPM` console.
It creates this database:

[This table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DifHH.png)

Which doesn't make any sense to me because this is my Connection string

`"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=MuLanuhcer; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"`

However it does use the updated version.

Now when I want to use this version of the database it work "perfectly"

But when I call the database context from my code it creates another database, This time with the correct name

[The same *exact* table but this time with the correct name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iHT4.png)

And when I try to add a row to one of my models it adds it to the second databse.

**Now let's say I want to update one of my models**

Let's take for example a News Update model I have

```
public class NewsUpdateModel
{
    public int RowID { get; set; }

    public int UpdateID { get; set; }

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }

    public string Headline { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishingDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add a Url Property to it. So I add a new Url property and again, Add a new migration and update the database

However this time it only updates the first database "MuLauncherServer.Relational.Context" and when I try to use the database from code it throws an exception saying that the context's model has changed.

It seems to be using one database to update and one database to do `CRUD` operations and (un)surprisingly this doesn't work

Comment: What you show on the image in "this table" is a database, not a table.

Comment: Most probably, you have different connection strings in different places. Do you have separate project for DAL? Do you have App.config inside it? Where do you store your connection string and how do you pass it to your db context?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I have a DLL for Entity Framework Interactions and a WPF(for now) project for the server. I have the database connection string inside the server's app.Config file. I pass the connection through the DI initialization inside the OnStartup method

Comment: Take a look at your project, which is for EF interactions. Perhaps, there is an `App.config` file which contains connection string with "MuLauncherServer.Relational.Context". Anyway, you can pass your own connection string to `Update-Database` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I have no other connection string, I've checked. And that is a good suggestion. I will try it right now

Comment: This is interesting. I've tried your way with explicitly adding the connection string to the update statement and it seems to have worked. However, when I try to add a new migration it saying that there are still pending migrations